# Unable to enter sendkeys value in android automation?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am unable to enter the mobile number in mobile number field.

[image]

```
   AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
  DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
  caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "W89DN7UGWWPBHUJZ");
  caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
  caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.0");
  caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.app.operator");
  caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.app.operator.MainActivity");

  driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
  WebElement mobileNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Mobile No']"));
  mobileNo.click();
  mobileNo.sendKeys("9999999999");
```

Comment: were you able to click on mobile no field?

Comment: Yes, I can able to lunch my app and then it's selecting mobile number field also. But after that when I am sending mobile number, number is not showing in entry field.

Comment: Does it show any error in appium server log? Which appium server version are you using? Also try adding ("automationName", "uiautomator2") in your DesiredCapabilities.

Comment: I am using Appium v1.13.0

Comment: ("automationName", "uiautomator2")  also not working

Comment: Try `//android.widget.EditText[@index='1']`

Comment: everything is clicking but it is not showing enter values. For e.g if for mobilenumber, I am giving mobile number and I am expecting number should be entered but i can't see whether my number is putting or not. I think it can't type sendkeys value